# How to determine when given a set of triangle triangles which has the smallest angle

Tags: c

I have been trying to create a program that determines:
when given a set of right angle triangles which has the smallest angle.
But i am having a lot of difficulty i have deduced that if a is a side length and b and c is the hypotenuse that is a

```
float a, b, c, a1, b1, c1;
float sinTheta, sinTheta1;

printf ("Please enter values for a, b, c\n");
scanf ("%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c);

printf ("Please enter values for a1, b1, c1\n");
scanf ("%f%f%f", &a1, &b1, &c1);


sinTheta=a/c;
sinTheta1=a1/c1;

if (sinTheta < sinTheta1)
    printf ("the triangle a b c has the smaller angle\n");

    else
        if (sinTheta > sinTheta1)
            printf ("The triangle a1, b1, c1 has the smaller angle\n");

return 0;
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the angles of a triangle?

Comment: do you have a shift key or any punctuation on your keyboard without those the sentences are hard to follow

Comment: The law of cosines will help if have the side lengths.  Wikipedia, Wolfram Mathworld, and a gazillion other sites have the formula.  You don't even need to take inverse cosines...the smallest angle has the greatest cosine.

Comment: I have tried a basic program that can tell the user which of the two right handle triangle has the smaller angle but i am not sure how to change it so that the program and do the same but for n amount of triangles

Comment: @user2900361 Please add your source code to your original post, otherwise no one can help you because it seems that no one really understands what the actual question is.

Comment: `sinTheta=a/c` is only true for right-angled triangles.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add in the description that i am using this program for right angle triangles only!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about solving a geometry problem rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your full source code, some parts are missing. You may import `<stdio.h>` by writing

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

at the beginning of the code.

Furthermore, there is no `main() { ... }`.
You may also handle the case that both angles are equal `sinTheta == sinTheta1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

float a, b, c, a1, b1, c1;
float sinTheta, sinTheta1;

printf ("Please enter values for a, b, c\n");
scanf ("%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c);

printf ("Please enter values for a1, b1, c1\n");
scanf ("%f%f%f", &a1, &b1, &c1);


sinTheta=a/c;
sinTheta1=a1/c1;

if (sinTheta < sinTheta1) {
    printf ("the triangle a b c has the smaller angle\n");
}
else if (sinTheta > sinTheta1) {
     printf ("The triangle a1, b1, c1 has the smaller angle\n");
}
else 
{
    printf ("the angles are the same\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

BTW: The value for `b` is redundant.

EDIT:

Quick & dirty approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

float a, c;
float sinTheta;

float sinThetaMin;
int nMin;
int nTriangle=2;  // specifies the number of triangles
int i;


for (i=0; i<nTriangle; i++) {
    printf ("Please enter values for a, c for triangle %d\n", i+1);
    scanf ("%f%f", &a, &c);
    sinTheta = a/c;
    printf("%f\n", sinTheta);
    if (i == 0) {
        sinThetaMin = sinTheta;
        nMin = i+1;
    }
    else {
        if (sinTheta < sinThetaMin) {
                sinThetaMin = sinTheta;
                nMin = i+1;
        }
    }

}

printf("Smallest triangle is number %d with a/c = %f\n", nMin, sinThetaMin);

return 0;
}
```